# Sniff on SWITCH(lan) traffic openWRT

Tags: iptables, routing, openwrt

Is it possible to sniff (with `tcpdump`) or mirror LAN traffic that doesn't get routed to WAN using `openWRT`?  Say  I have two PCs connected to LAN ports and I want to sniff on traffic one PC is sending to the other one? 
--`tee` feature is of no use in this case as nothing gets routed and therefore `iptables` cannot pick it.
I have read somewhere that such thing might be possible by implementing VLANs but frankly I don't understand how. I have `openWRT` firmware on DIR-300 and Linksys E1200.